# Angularjs hide DOM elements but still draw them so directive events fire?

Tags: angularjs, handsontable

I'm using [ngHandsontable](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable) in an angular ui-router app. My table take 1-2 seconds to render (10x20 cells, which isnt create but fine ...).

The issue is that I cant use angular ng-if or ng-show to hide the table and show a loading template until the afterRender events fire because if I hide the hot-table dir like that, then the DOM is never drawn and obviously the afterRender event wont fire.

Any suggestions how to show a loading template while table is rendering? I'm thinking maybe an overlay? Is there an angular directive that will hide the DOM element but still insert/draw it?

```
<hot-table></hot-table>
```